# arff library with python for dealing with np.nan values

Tags: python, numpy, weka, arff

I use arff library in python
[arff library](https://pypi.org/project/arff/) in order to transform "numpy" array to arff file and read it with Weka. The issue I am facing Weka expects missing values as `?` and arff library use as `nan`,

therefore the row looks like

> 0.0,0.0,-60.0,0.0,nan,nan

but Weka expects

> 0.0,0.0,-60.0,0.0,?,?

I tries to `fillna` with `"?"` but then it will appear as

> 0.0,0.0,-60.0,0.0,'?','?'

which is still not parsed by Weka because of the `'`, one solution would be to remove all `'` signs, is there any more ideas?

Comment: In python, `nan` is a float. `'?'` is a character. The quotes are an inherent part of a string display.

Comment: This is a small old (2011) library.